# Where Left Join in Eloquent, Give parameter of parent table

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a simple query that I should run with eloquent as the following

```
 SELECT `followers`.*, `fol`.`followed_id` AS `is_fan` 
    FROM `followers` 
    LEFT JOIN `followers` AS `fol` ON `fol`.`follower_id` = `followers`.`followed_id` 
         AND fol.followed_id = ?
    WHERE `followers`.`followed_type` = ?    
    AND `followers`.`followed_id` = ? 
    GROUP BY `followers`.`followed_id`, `fol`.`followed_id`  
    ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

Then I made a possible correct query with eloquent:

```
$this->follow->with('follower')
             ->where('followers.followed_type', $followed['follower_type'])
             ->where('followers.followed_id',$followed['follower_id'])
             ->leftJoin('followers as fol',function($join) use ($followed)
             {
                $join->on('fol.follower_id','=','followers.followed_id')
                      ->where('fol.followed_id','=','followers.follower_id');
             })
             ->groupBy('followers.followed_id')
             ->groupBy('fol.followed_id')
             ->select('followers.*',"fol.followed_id as is_fan")
             ->get();
```

After a lots time of debugging for understand why the column `is_fan` wasn't populated as excepted I tried to hard code the value passed on the `where` In the join closure for see a response like so:

```
->leftJoin('followers as fol',function($join) use ($followed)
                 {
                    $join->on('fol.follower_id','=','followers.followed_id')
                          ->where('fol.followed_id','=',1);
                 })
```

And it has worked, so i came with the solution that the third parameter cannot be a parameter of the parent table in this case `followers`. There is any possibility to get the value of the parent table e pass it as third parameter in the `where` method in the `LeftJoin` closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with your code is, that `where` use parameter binding, thus `'followers.follower_id'` treated like a string here:

```
->where('fol.followed_id','=','followers.follower_id');
```

`DB::raw()` is not enough here, because `JoinClause`s `where` works a bit defferently, and apparently you simply need another `on`:

```
->on('fol.followed_id','=','followers.follower_id');
```

Comment: Hey @deczo Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work, I tried with both. It give the same issue doesn't show the value of `is_fan` column. Any other idea? Even if your answer was seem right to me, but it didn't work so strange.

Comment: 2 questions: what is `$this->follow` and what result you expect exactly? Show example code you run after that query, where `is_fan` should be accessible.

Comment: https://github.com/fenos/Rally/blob/master/src/Fenos/Rally/Repositories/RallyPolymorphicRepository.php#L64 This is the function with in that query i think will be all more clear to you :). Really appreciated your help

Comment: Your code should return a `Collection` with models that have `is_fan` property: `$result->first()->is_fan;` If you cast it to array or whatever then it should be accessed accordingly, but definitely should be there.

Comment: Yes it is return correct the column,it is present on the collection how you said but the problem that is not filled correctly, (`is_fan` is just an alias of the query). I thought that the problem is calling a parent column as value instead a proper value. How I said if i hard code the value the query work like a charm. I'm confusing about that. Again Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, you're right. This `where` method works differently and, though the query looks almost the same, you need to use `on` instead. Check the edit, this should do the job.

Comment: I cannot believe myself, I spent minimum 2 hours for this. Thanks so much for your patient and knowledge. Really Appreciated. It works like a charm